# What do the “(1)” notifications under the Gold Apples and Starfruit buttons mean?

Tags: fruit-ninja

[image: "(1)" under Gold Apple and Starfruit buttons]

As you can see, there's a "(1)" under both the Gold Apples and Starfruit buttons. I've tried tapping them, but there's nothing seemingly pertaining to the "notifications". I've already claimed the "thank you" Starfruit × 500 and Gold Apple × 20 bonuses (last page of the Featured tab of the pop-up that opens by pressing on either of the two buttons, i.e. the Store), but the "(1)"s don't go away. I've also tried searching it online, but haven't found anything.

Is there a way to make them go? They somewhat annoy me, and I feel like I'm missing something.

Update: So far, I have debunked the theory that it represents the availability of a video I can watch so that I can earn Golden Apples or Starfruit, since it's still showing after turning the Internet access off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just to tell you of new deals and all the sort. I've seen them on other gameplay videos, and it's entirely the same.

Don't worry, you're not missing any items, just some (expensive) discounts!

Cheers!

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I've tried to "buy" them and then cancel the purchase, and the (1)s are still there, so it kind of urges me to actually buy them. However, what is strange is that it's a 1 and not some more relevant number.

Comment: Did you click on the deals and see if that helped?

Comment: Yeah, hasn't helped. I suspect it might be some sort of a fake notification which is intentionally designed to not be related to the actual number of items so that I check. I have debunked the theory that it might be the availability of a video to watch so that I earn more of a currency.

Comment: Mhm, probably an aesthetic or just something to trick you into paying. Oh well, glad everything has been resolved. Thanks for accepting my answer!